# Finding two near identical values mysql

Tags: php, mysql, gps

After searching for quite some time I have been unable to discover or write the proper mysql query for a function that evaluates the uniqueness(or near uniqueness) of a GPS point. This includes a latitude and longitude evaluation within the same database row.

The database **roads** has rows for **roadid**, **lat**, and **lng**.

The issue is that the API that I am using does not always return *exactly* the same value as previous calls, I assume they are interpolated. Nonetheless, this means that a response might be "35.000000, 40.000000" and next time be "35.000008, 39.999992."

I want to write a PHP function that will be passed a database object, latitude, longitude, and tolerance. The tolerance should be applied to both the latitude and longitude points, so that any points within the "tolerance area" will be found.

It should return either true(No matching results based on tolerance and lat/long given) OR it should return the mysql response object for handling and further evaluation of the non-unique point(s).

Here's what I have so far:

```
private function checkunique($db, $lat, $lng, $tolerance = 0)
{
    //check database for lat/lng
    $response = $db->query("SELECT roadid FROM roads WHERE lat = " . $lat . " AND lng = " . $lng);
    if($response->num_rows == 0)
    {
        //unique
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //duplicate or duplicate within tolerance found.
        $response = $response->fetch_object();
        return $response;
    }
}
```

I assume the only thing I really need is a proper MySQL statement, but I'm tagging this in PHP too.

Comment: Are you using DECIMAL or a FLOAT data type?

Comment: They are FLOAT values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you just need this:

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE $lat BETWEEN (lat - $tolerance AND lat + $tolerance)
```

or

```
WHERE (abs(lat - $lat) <= $tolerance)
```

Comment: Wouldn't LIKE (or similar) be more appropriate to find near identical values? OP's question's title reads as "Finding two near identical values mysql".

Comment: not really. like would force a string conversion. between and abs versions would stay numeric.

Comment: like would also fail for stuff, e.g. `like '39.92%'` won't help if the lower tolerance range is 39.89 -> 39.95